# How to create a view in the Java BigQuery API?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Using the Java client library for Google BigQuery, how does one create a view?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Searched the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant API call is [tables.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert). With the Java API, this is represented by the [`create` method on the BigQuery service object](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.18.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#create-com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableInfo-com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.TableOption...-). You first have to create a `TableInfo`, which encapsulates a `ViewDefinition` object. The documentation for [`setDefinition`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.18.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/TableInfo.Builder.html#setDefinition-com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDefinition-) on `TableInfo.Builder` says:

> Sets the table definition. Use StandardTableDefinition to create
>   simple BigQuery table. Use ViewDefinition to create a BigQuery view.
>   Use ExternalTableDefinition to create a BigQuery a table backed by
>   external data.

Sample code:

```
bigQuery.create(TableInfo.of(TableId.of("DatasetName", "ViewName"),
        ViewDefinition.of("SELECT this, is, the, view FROM query")))
```